# ReadyRoll Project: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: sql, redgate, readyroll

I did the import earlier. The target database that I was using was deleted accidentally but it was restored from the backup. When I did a refresh, I found the following error,

**An item with the same key has already been added**
[image]

The shadow database that was created earlier was deleted as well.

Comment: Sorry about the error. Do you see a button that says *Copy Details* when the error appears? If so can you please click it and paste+send the output to us? You can edit your question or post it in our support forum:
https://forums.red-gate.com/viewforum.php?f=199&sid=aacf9e621a14ec3ddc5c1479f43fdf88

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Copy Details button in the ReadyRoll DBSync window or the Error List/ Output window. Any other way?

Comment: Would you mind please providing a screenshot of the entire VS window?

Comment: I added the screenshot of the entire VS window.

Comment: Thanks for doing posting that. Unfortunately since the stack trace isn't showing here, can you please send us (support@ready-roll.com) your ReadyRoll log file. This can be found in the following location:
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\rrlog.txt

Comment: I have sent an email attached with the rrlog file to Redgate support.

Comment: @dsingh23 Was there any response from Redgate support that would be relevant to the rest of us? It would be useful to know potential solutions if others have this problem as well.